# Can not open the mobaXterm | install ohmyzsh

Tags: oh-my-zsh, mobaxterm

I tried installing "ohmyzsh" from git hub page[https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH]

I install the zsh first but when I restarted the MobaXterm again, it failed with the following error.

[image]

Now I can not work with MobaXterm. Please help.